# Given a path of an image, how to display the image contented in that path

Tags: android, sqlite, uri

I saved a path of an image taken by the camera into sqlite DB as the following:
retrievePath() method is to retrieve the saved path from the DB.

`getImageUri(imgPath)` method is to cobvert the file path into uri.

```
OnClickListener btn_TakePictureListener = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imgPath = retrievePath();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri(imgPath));
        startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode);
    }
};

    private File retrievePath() {
    int []x = imgOpHlpr.getIDs();
    String s = imgOpHlpr.getImg_Path(x.length);
    File file = new File(s);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "retrieved path "+s.toString(),    
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return file;            
}   

private Uri getImageUri(File path) {
    Uri imgFileUri = Uri.fromFile(path);
    return imgFileUri;
}
```

and what i want to know now is: after retrieving the path from the DB, how to display the contents of that path in an imageView. in other words, ofcourse the path of the image contains data, i want to display the contented data inside an `ImageView`.

How to do so?

Comment: is it the data (something like text) or the image is present in that image path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath));
```